# reload UIPickerView on uncurl/dismiss of modal segue; partial curl

Tags: ios, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a ViewController with a UIPickerView and a settingsViewController that is called with a modal segue partial curl.

I need to be able to pass `[examplePicker reloadAllComponents]` when the segue is dismissed, all methods I have tried, either have no effect or stop the animation and leave me stuck on the settingsViewController.